# HtmlEncode text in DetailsView in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, detailsview

I have taken over a project where HtmlDecode has been run on all data in the database. I will now use the asp:DetailsView to edit the data. The problem is that the asp:BoundField does not encode the data so that it appears correctly in edit mode. How do I solve that?

Comment: Are you sure it's not encoded and needs decoded?  Usually when it's not displaying properly, it's encoded.

Comment: When the text is displayed on the page, it is properly decoded. But when the text are edited in a textbox, the text are still decoded, and &###; are displayed insted of the correct chars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to set the HtmlEncode property on the asp:Boundfield to true. When this property is set to true, the data will be encoded before it appears.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode.aspx